# How do I fix a php file_get_contents warning caused by a negative number in JSON content?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, zoho

I'm trying to use file_get_contents() to perform an SQL query using Zoho's COQL API (https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/Get-Records-through-COQL-Query.html) to get a list of customers within a longitude and latitude boundary. When I pass my SQL statement, `file_get_contents()` fails to open the stream.

I've been troubleshooting this for the better part of two hours now, and from what I can tell, the issue only occurs when a negative number is present in the query. If I remove the hyphen, I'm able to perform a successful query and get a response from the server. I don't understand what's going on or how to fix it.

I've changed the longitude and latitude numbers for privacy, but otherwise this is the code I'm using.

```php
$query = "select Last_Name, First_Name, Mailing_Street, Mailing_City, Mailing_State, Mailing_Zip, Latitude, Longitude
      from Contacts
      where (Latitude between 29.831755 and 29.889647)
      and (Longitude between -114.994548 and -115.069968)";

private function perform_query(){
        $data = json_encode(["select_query" => $this->query]);
        $result = file_get_contents($this->config['coql_url'], FALSE, stream_context_create([
            'http' => [
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
                "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken " . $this->access_token,
                'content' => $data
            ]
        ]));
        var_dump($http_response_header);
        var_dump($data);
        var_dump($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

Here's the output of the `var_dump()`s:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/coql): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 
 in <b>/home2/.../src/coql.php</b> on line <b>54</b><br />
array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "HTTP/1.1 401 "
  [1]=>
  string(11) "Server: ZGS"
  [2]=>
  string(35) "Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2019 01:25:28 GMT"
  [3]=>
  string(44) "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"
  [4]=>
  string(18) "Content-Length: 87"
  [5]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [6]=>
  string(63) "Set-Cookie: ...; Path=/"
  [7]=>
  string(31) "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"
  [8]=>
  string(31) "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block"
  [9]=>
  string(83) "Set-Cookie: crmcsr=...;path=/;Secure;priority=high"
  [10]=>
  string(16) "Pragma: no-cache"
  [11]=>
  string(23) "Cache-Control: no-cache"
  [12]=>
  string(38) "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
  [13]=>
  string(71) "Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=...; Path=/; Secure"
  [14]=>
  string(26) "X-Download-Options: noopen"
}
string(262) "{"select_query":"select Last_Name, First_Name, Mailing_Street, Mailing_City, Mailing_State, Mailing_Zip, Latitude, Longitude\n      from Contacts\n      where (Latitude between 29.831755 and 29.889647)\n      and (Longitude between -114.994548 and -115.069968)"}"
bool(false)
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Try to add double quotes: ... `"-114.994548" and "-115.069968"`

Comment: Also, you need to put the lower number first so its  `"-115.069968" and "-114.994548"`

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the numerical order and suggestion. I just tried using different variations of quotation marks with no success. I tried: wrapping the numbers in single quotes, back ticks, escaped double quotes, and using double quotes wrapped in single quotes ( ' " ' ) with no success.

Comment: I have also tried replacing the minus sign with the HTML code (&#45;) with no success.

Comment: Still the same error? Can you try something like CURL and not `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Yeah, still the same error. I had a similar thought to try CURL and it seems to have gone through. The Zoho server this time throws an error. Telling me that it expects the values for Longitude to be doubles. I'm trying to get some insight from Zoho's customer service.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you put the method and content inside the header. That's incorrect. It needs to be in the array and moved outside the header, such as:

```
$sResponse = @ file_get_contents($sURL,FALSE,stream_context_create(array('http'=>array(
    'ignore_errors' => TRUE, // critical if you want to see errors in response instead of empty on error
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken $sAccessToken",
        'cache-control: no-cache'
    ),
    'content' => $sJSON
))));
```